kickstart with virt-install for ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to avoid answering user configuration data during a VM installation via virtg-install. Trying kickstart option with the following procedure:
'''
HOSTNAME=css_vm1
BRIDGE="br-control"
ISO_FQN="/root/ubuntu/ubuntu-22.04.4-live-server-amd64.iso,kernel=casper/vmlinuz,initrd=casper/initrd"
KS_FILE="/root/ubuntu/ks_merged.cfg"
VCPUS=2
VM_IMAGE_PATH="/var/lib/libvirt/images/ubuntu-vm1.qcow2"
DISK_SIZE=10
RAM_SIZE=4096
virt-install 
--name "${HOSTNAME}" 
--network bridge="${BRIDGE}" 
--disk size=${DISK_SIZE},path=${VM_IMAGE_PATH},format=qcow2
--ram "${RAM_SIZE}" 
--vcpus "${VCPUS}" 
--os-type linux 
--os-variant ubuntu22.04
--extra-args="ks=file:/${KS_FILE} console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial" 
--graphics=none 
--noautoconsole 
--debug 
--location "${ISO_FQN}"
'''
The kickstart file is the one that I generated from ubuntu GUI using kickstart generator amd it looks like the following:
'''
#cat ks_merged.cfg
#Generated by Kickstart Configurator
#platform=x86
#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone --utc Etc/UTC
#Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $1$pso.SRUz$3CigNdJOEzSlLpr/yjv0m/
#Initial user
user css --fullname "CSS" --iscrypted --password 1$IoisLw0t$biurHVhzlndQWuiPbGi3K1
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel
#Disk partitioning information
part swap --size 200 --asprimary
part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow --asprimary
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5
#Network information
network --bootproto=static --ip=192.168.10.10 --netmask=255.255.255.248 --gateway=192.168.10.8 --nameserver=192.168.10.14 --device=enp1s0
#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled
#Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
#Package install information
%packages
@ ubuntu-server
%post --nochroot
apt-get update -y
'''
I still see the questions being asked at the console, as if the file is not being read at all. I don't want to embed the file ISO as it has a hardcoded interface name, somethings in the file might need dynamic change from environment to environment, like interface name, disk name etc. I need this to work to be able to avoid effort in manual configurations of VMs during installation, and would appreciate a quick response.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How to install a vm on ubuntu 22.04 using virt-install and a kickstart file avoid interaction to  answer the questions during installation
